# Power BI (DAX): Distinct Count Filtered by Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, dax, powerbi

I have a data set with publishers with revenue by month. Publishers are considered to be "active" month if their revenue is equal or greater than 1000 for a given month.

Now, I want to count the distinct number of "active" publishers over a monthly trend using Power BI (DAX).

Example Data Set

[image: Example Data Set]

Here is a measure formula that I attempted:

```
DistCountActiveMonths = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('Net Revenue Data'[Publisher Name]),FILTER('Net Revenue Data','Net Revenue Data'[Active Month]=1))
```

Please advise how to correct this formula to achieve the desired result, e.g.:

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
DistinctCountActiveMonths =
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT( 'Net Revenue Data'[Publisher Name] )
    ,'Net Revenue Data'[Active Month] = 1
)
```

Comment: thanks, I have a follow on question to this. Would you mind taking a look? Power BI (DAX): Calculating MoM Variance of a Measure Field http://stackoverflow.com/q/35441610/153639